# Apple Mac Mini won't work with HDMI to VGA converter

Tags: conversion, mac, vga

I bought an Apple Mac Mini i5 yesterday. My Samsung 19" monitor only has a VGA input, so I bought an HDMI to VGA converter cable. The monitor won't detect my Mac Mini device when I connect them with the converter. Why not/what can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following information on [Apple's Site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4214):

> The HDMI port will drive digital connections—such as DVI—using the
>   adapter that came with the Mac mini, but cannot be used for analog
>   displays such as VGA. You can purchase a Mini DisplayPort to VGA
>   adapter separately to drive analog displays.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me that can I use ThunderBolt port as Mini DisplayPort  ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, @leo! Comments aren't the right place for follow-up questions on this site. If you need that information, please ask it as a separate question, perhaps with a link to this one for reference.

Comment: Thunderbolt is backwards compatible with Mini DisplayPort, so a Mini DisplayPort adapter will work with the Thunderbolt port on the Mac Mini.